# react + redux: Cannot read property 'handleClickMenu' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to the reagent and Redux. I am trying to make the menu, but the console getting error:

> App.js?eb5a:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClickMenu' of undefined

*How to fix the error?
As the payload in a new state record?*

App.js:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import User from '../components/User'
import Page from '../components/Page'
import BottomMenu from '../components/BottomMenu'
import * as pageActions from '../actions/PageActions'
import * as userActions from '../actions/UserActions'
import * as bmenuActions from '../actions/BottomMenuActions'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { user, page, bottomMenu } = this.props
    const { getPhotos } = this.props.pageActions
    const { handleClickMenu } = this.props.bmenuActions
    const { handleLogin } = this.props.userActions

    return <div className='row'>
      <Page photos={page.photos} year={page.year} getPhotos={getPhotos} fetching={page.fetching} error={page.error}/>
      <User name={user.name} handleLogin={handleLogin} error={user.error} />
        <BottomMenu selectedItem={bottomMenu.selectedItem} bmenuClick={() => handleClickMenu} />
    </div>
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.user,
    page: state.page,
    bottomMenu: state.bottomMenu
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    pageActions: bindActionCreators(pageActions, dispatch),
    userActions: bindActionCreators(userActions, dispatch),
    bmenuActions: bindActionCreators(bmenuActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

component bottomMenu.js:

```
    import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
import BottomMenuItem from '../components/BottomMenuItem'

export default class BottomMenu extends Component {


    render() {

        const { selectedItem, bmenuClick } = this.props;

        const menuItems = [{
            url: 'home',
            name: 'Главная страница'
        }, {
            url: 'goods',
            name: 'Объем поставок'
        }, {
            url: 'geo',
            name: 'География поставок'
        }, {
            url: 'clients',
            name: 'Клиенты и партнеры'
        }, {
            url: 'production',
            name: 'Виды продукции'
        }, {
            url: 'cost',
            name: 'Рассчитайте стоимость'
        }, {
            url: '',
            name: 'Свяжитесь с нами'
        }];

        return <ul className='footer-menu'>

            { menuItems.map((item,index) =>  <BottomMenuItem key={index} item={item} selected={index === selectedItem} bmenuClick={bmenuClick} /> )}

        </ul>
    }
}


BottomMenu.propTypes = {
    item: PropTypes.object,
    selected: PropTypes.bool
}
```

component BottomMenuItem.js:

```
    import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'

export default class BottomMenuItem extends Component {

bmenu_Click(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.bmenuClick(e)
}

  render() {
    const { item, selected} = this.props

    const className = 'footer-menu__li footer-menu__li--' + item.url + (selected ? ' footer-menu__li--current' : '')

    return <li className={className}>
        {!selected ?
        <a href={item.url} className='footer-menu__href' onClick={::this.bmenu_Click}>{item.name}</a>
        :
        <span className='footer-menu__href'>{item.name}</span>
        }
        </li>
    }
}

BottomMenuItem.propTypes = {
    item: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    selected: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    bmenuClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

action: BottomMenuAction.js

```
    export function handleClickMenu(el) {

console.log(el)

  return function(dispatch) {

    dispatch({
        type: 'bmenuClick',
        payload:''
    })

  }

}
```

Comment: It seems like you forget to pass the function reference to the `App` component. `<App bMenuActions=.... />`

Comment: You have a mismatch of casing on the following: const { handleClickMenu } = this.props.bMenuActions

Comment: You have attached Action to props as `bmenuActions` and using as `bMenuActions`

Comment: I did not understand how to do?

Answer (score 0):

A few mistakes in your code

First is a typo where you bindAction as `bmenuActions` and then in your `App.js` you are using it with the wrong case as `const { handleClickMenu } = this.props.bMenuActions`. You need to change that to `const { handleClickMenu } = this.props.bmenuActions`

Also now since here `handleClickMenu` is a function you need to bind it while passing down to `BottomMenu` component like

```
<BottomMenu selectedItem={bmenu.selectedItem} bmenuClick={() => handleClickMenu} />
```

Now again in App.js your state is available as `bottomMenu` and you are resolving it like `bmenu`. Change it to

```
const { user, page, bottomMenu } = this.props
```

Now from `BottomMenu` component you are sending the props as `bmenuClick` to the `BottomMenuItem` component like

```
   return <ul className='footer-menu'>

        { menuItems.map((item,index) =>  <BottomMenuItem key={index} item={item} selected={item === selectedItem} bmenuClick={() => bmenuClick }/> )}

    </ul>
```

but you are using it in your `BottomMenuItem` component as `this.props.handleClickMenu` here

```
bmenu_Click(e){
    this.props.handleClickMenu(e)
}
```

You need to change it as

```
bmenu_Click(e){
    this.props.bmenuClick(e)
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, now the error in the console: App.js?eb5a:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedItem' of undefined

Comment: Check the update, bmenu is not available in App.js its `bottomMenu`

Comment: Eeeeee! Thank you. Menu appears on the screen! But preventing the console: Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `item` was not specified in `BottomMenu`. Check the render method of `App`.
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `selected` was not specified in `BottomMenu`. Check the render method of `App`.
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `onSelectedItemChanged` was not specified in `BottomMenu`. Check the render method of `App`.

They pay attention to?

Comment: No Problem, glad to have helped. You posting the entire code helped in quick debugging.

Comment: Preventing the console: 

Warning: Failed propType: Required prop item was not specified in BottomMenu. Check the render method of App. 
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop selected was not specified in BottomMenu. Check the render method of App. 
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop onSelectedItemChanged was not specified in BottomMenu. Check the render method of App. 

They pay attention to?

Comment: Follow the warnings closelt, they convey all the info, for eg in `BottomMenu.propTypes = {
    item: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    selected: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    onSelectedItemChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}` you have item as prop but you are not passing it to the component so remove it. Similarly check for the others. I think you can do it based on the hint.

Comment: warning corrected. Now, I do not understand why when you click on the link does not work handleClickMenu in BottomMenuAstion.js

Comment: .@alexandr2006 there is some issue with binding. Also I more thing that I can spot is that in your map function you are not binding `bmenuClick`. I think that will help. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I've done:

```
<BottomMenuItem key={index} item={item} pos={index} selected={index === selectedItem} bmenuClick={bmenuClick} />
```

and

```
<a href={item.url} className='footer-menu__href' onClick={::this.bmenu_Click} data-pos={pos}>{item.name}</a>
```